# Why is the string inside my struct a random letter/number?

Tags: c, string, struct

Whenever I assign a string in my struct to a name and print out the name it just shows random letters and numbers.

```
typedef struct Per {
     char *name;
     char sex;
     struct Person *father;  
     struct Person *mother;
     Dllist children;
} * Person;

Person newPerson(char * name) {
     Person p = malloc(sizeof(struct Per));

     p->name = strdup(name);
     p->sex = ' ';
     p->father = NULL;
     p->mother = NULL;
     p->children = new_dllist();
}

//in main
Person p = newPerson("BOB");
printf("%s\n", p->string);
```

it should be printing "BOB" but instead prints out "G", "Px", "0i".

Comment: Where is `return p;` from `newPerson` function ?

Comment: @rafix07 wow. I am just an idiot lol. I didn't think of that, thanks!

Comment: This code can’t compile as Person doesn’t have a member called ”string”.

Comment: You should not *think* of that. You should tell the compiler to do the check for you, **always**, no exceptions. C compilers are horrendously bad at showing programmer errors by default, but no worries, just crank up the warning level and all is well again. Use `-Wall -Werror` or `/W3 /WX` depending on your compiler. https://godbolt.org/z/PmIL_k